# Instagram Real time API - PHP - Unable to get POST Update

Tags: php, api, post, instagram

I'm trying to connect with the instagram API, the connection works fine and I am receiving the updates just as described in the API documentation, the issue is that I cannot access to the data send to my callback function.

According to the [doc](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)

> When someone posts a new photo and it triggers an update of one of your subscriptions, we make a POST request to the callback URL that you defined in the subscription

This is my code :

```
// check if we have a security challenge
if (isset ($_GET['hub_challenge']))
            echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];  
    else // This is an update
    {
        // read  the content of $_POST
        $myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $answer = json_decode($myString);

        // This is not working  starting from here
        $id = $answer->{'object_id'};
        $api = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/'.$id.'/media/recent?client_secret='.INSTA_CLI_SECRET.'&client_id='.INSTA_CLI_ID;

        $response = get_curl($api); //change request path to pull different photos
        $images = array();

        if($response){
        $decode = json_decode($response);
        foreach($decode->{'data'} as $item){
             // do something with the data here
             }
        }
    }
```

Displaying the $myString variable I have this result, don't know why it is not decoded to json :(

> [{"changed_aspect": "media", "subscription_id": 2468174, "object":
>   "geography", "object_id": "1518250", "time": 1350044500}]

the get_curl function is working fine when I hardcode my $id.

I guess something is wrong with my $myString, unfortunately the $_POST cvariable is not populated, Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: You should use `$answer->object_id` instead, rather than referencing objects wrapped with `{''}`, you can access it directly in plain, i.e. `$obj->method_name`.

Comment: I'm getting an error doing so :  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: The object is in an array. Try `$answer[0]->object_id`.

Comment: Oh, and if that doesn't work, just add `var_dump($answer)` to see what the structure of this variable is exactly.

Comment: Thanks Arno, this was exactly the solution !

Comment: @ArnoMoonen Since you have provided a solution, please post it as an answer so that others who search for this may find the answer.

Comment: @ShyamK I added it as an answer.

Comment: @yumyum What exactly did you end up with? I am having the very same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example JSON response included in your question, I can conclude that the object you are trying to talk with is wrapped in an array (hence the [ and ] around it in the JSON string).

You should access it using `$answers[0]->object_id`.
If that doesn't work, you can always use `var_dump` to check out the data in one of your variables.